# "Your request could not be completed" - iTunes url error

Tags: ios, app-store

I want my app to redirect user on the application's page at the app store. The problem is that it keeps showing "Your request could not be completed" alert, whether the request is definitely correct (I used itunes linkmaker for that).
The only thing I'm not sure about is that the app is on German appstore, when I use an US appleID on it. Could it be the cause of the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has your app been released? This won't work if your app hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Yes, it has been released. And link works if I open it in browser on my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that you really just can't access the item which is on German appstore using US appleId. Basically, I think the same issue for any countries - appleId's country should match the appstore's country application is available at.
But if on my mac itunes just redirected me, it didn't work for the device.
Might it will help somebody.